# Webpack does not load jQuery

Tags: jquery, webpack

I am starting to learn about webpack, and I am trying to apply it to my ASP.Net project, overwriting the default bundling utilities.

However, even though I set up webpack and co. according to some tutorials online, I am kind of lost on how to properly get jQuery into my bundle.

The problem: 'jQuery' is not defined when trying to call it in the chrome dev tools console. I checked the bundle.js, and even though it says something about jQuery, the source code for that is very short and by no means the complete jQuery source.

Here is my webpack.config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        site: [
            './Scripts/index.ts'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist/')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
    ]
};
```

The index.ts does not contain any real code yet, but only one line, being:

```
import $ = require("jQuery");
```

which, as far as I understood webpack, should tell webpack to put the jQuery source into the bundle.js, as it is required.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you don't need to require or import jquery from a module. You should just use `$` or `jQuery` inside of your index.ts.
And don't forget to `npm install jquery`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue like 2 days ago what solved the issue,

1. install jquery (npm install jquery)
2. Add resolve in
   webpack.config, a folder location webpack try to search and resolve the requested module (in this case jquery)

E.g.

```
resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.join(__dirname, "./app/custom-path"), //this is optional
            "node_modules"
        ]
    },
```

Also to make jquery variable available for other modules to be used in them(so that you don't have to write import $ from 'jquery')

```
plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        })
    ],
```